# Knockout.js & Bootstrap 3 - Bread Crumb Pseudo Element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have run into an interesting bug. The CSS pseudo element does **not** disappear when it's associated element has `display: none;` in Bootstrap 3.0.2's breadcrumb component. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/N65ck/) To test: try switching the mode in the view model from "Mode 1" to "Mode 2".

I have a breadcrumb link that I am building using knockout.js. I switch the visibility of the pure `li` or `li` with nested `a` with knockout's `visible: onSomeCondition` binding. My understanding is that the non-visible `li` is set with `display: none;`. **However**, this does not remove the associated `li` in the DOM, and I think that makes the CSS keep the pseudo element. For example, I am expecting the following:

```
Mode 1 / Mode 2
```

But I get:

/ Mode 1 / Mode 2

The relevant knockout code is:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li data-bind="visible: isInMode1()">
        <a href="#">Mode 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active" data-bind="visible: !isInMode1()">Mode 1</li>
    <li data-bind="visible: isInMode2()">
        <a href="#">Mode 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active" data-bind="visible: !isInMode2()">Mode 2</li>
</ol>
```

The relevant Bootstrap 3.0.2 CSS is below. Based on the Bootstrap style sheet, the "/" character is added as a pseudo "before" element.

```
.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.breadcrumb > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #cccccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

.breadcrumb > .active {
  color: #999999;
}
```

If there is a better way to do this, or a cross-browser solution that I am not thinking of, I would be grateful for any input. I would prefer not to hack the CSS, but that may be the cleaner solution.

Thank you

Quick Links:

[Bootstrap 3.0.2 Breadcrumbs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs)

[Knockout.js visible binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "visible" binding, the separator will show even if the element is hidden. Use the "if" and "ifnot" bindngs:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li data-bind="if:isInMode1()">
      <a href="#">Mode 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active" data-bind="ifnot:isInMode1()">Mode 1</li>
  <li data-bind="if:isInMode2()">
    <a href="#">Mode 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active" data-bind="ifnot:isInMode2()">Mode 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried this too. It seems as if this also sets display: none; It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, and because I very rarely find a question I can answer that doesn't already have a brilliant answer.....this is what to do:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" data-bind="foreach: contentModel.breadcrumbs">
        <!-- ko if: isInMode1($data) -->
        <li data-bind="css: cssClass">
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: displayName, click: $root.GetContent"></a>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: isInMode1($data) -->
        <li data-bind="css: cssClass, text: displayName"></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        ...repeat for isInMode2.......
    </ol>
```

The if: and ifnot: bindings only render SUB elements depending upon their evaluation.....The element that contains the if/ifnot binding is always rendered.